# Split document into two documents based on two fields (with aggregation)

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a document like this one:

```
{
  'name': 'douglas'
  'datetime_created': '2019-10-24',
  'datetime_expiration': '2019-01-12'
}
```

I want to split this document into two documents, by the fields `datetime_created` and `datetime_expiration`.
Expected output:

```
{
  'name': 'douglas'
  'datetime_created': '2019-10-24'
},
{
  'name': 'douglas'
  'datetime_expiration': '2019-01-12'
}
```

How can I do this with `aggregation`?

Comment: A bit interesting questions :-) :-) !! this as well : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59906392/apply-uppercase-in-all-the-fields-of-all-documents-aggregate/59906528#59906528 :)

Comment: Yeah thanks! This was cool

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In 3 steps:

Create array with 2 items + `$unwind` + [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) or [$replaceWith](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceWith/)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      data: [
        {
          name: "$name",
          datetime_created: "$datetime_created"
        },
        {
          name: "$name",
          datetime_expiration: "$datetime_expiration"
        },

      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$data"
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: "$data"
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mDkFFhMz5KP)

Comment: Nice solution. Thanks!